# Instantiating view frame so that it fits with navigation bar / tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame

I have an app where sometimes views are in navigation controllers, sometimes not, and sometimes in a tab bar and navigation controller.

I create my views programatically using code such as this:

```
let contact = ContactFormViewController(contactFormView: ContactFormView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds))
```

however this is causing frames to always be as large as the screen, meaning when there is a navigation bar or tab bar the view is pushed off the visible screen and doesnt fit.

Is there a method to adapt the view height to always show it all on screen regardless of parent elements like the nav bar or tab bar? or would it be a case of always creating views with manual subtractions like this, which seems poor as it needs to assume hardcoded elements:

```
let attendees = AttendeesViewController(attendeesView: AttendeesView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-55)))
```

thanks for any guidance as its a major issue in my app

Comment: Apple's prescribed way to do layout is called auto layout. That, combined with size classes, trait collections, and dynamic font sizes is as a group called adaptive layout. None of these use frames - and it works in all sizes of iOS devices.

Comment: i know how auto layout works, but you cant do that when init objects...you need to define a frame for a manual init of a view controller view

Comment: Just use `CGRect.zero` when forced to use a frame. That's what I do. (EDIT: Just saw your answer. Glad you found that!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set the frame to `CGRect.zero` and then in the init method of the controller, apply layout constraints to the view class to map it to `self.view`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong to take UIScreen as the reference to lay out your views. I think you should use the content view (the view at the top of your hierarchy) as the reference.

Comment: In general you can call it with self.view.frame. It depends if your are in a view controller or something else.